# Two different method generates same result in Fluent API Code First (WithOptional vs WithRequiredPrincipal)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I am reading [Configuring Relationships with the Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx) article from msdn.

But I am stuck in one place.

There is two parts with these names:

- Configuring a Required-to-Optional Relationship (One-to–Zero-or-One)
- Configuring a Relationship Where Both Ends Are Required (One-to-One)

And here is the codes:

```
    // Map one-to-zero or one relationship 
    modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeAssignment>()
                .HasRequired(t => t.Instructor)
                .WithOptional(t => t.OfficeAssignment);

    // Map one-to-one relationship 
    modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeAssignment>()
                .HasRequired(t => t.Instructor)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.OfficeAssignment);
```

Both of these generates same `CREATE TABLE` queries, there is not any difference.

But, of course there must be some difference which I can't see.

***What is the difference between `WithOptional` and `WithRequiredPrincipal`? When I should use which one?***

Thanks.

Comment: I can't confirm that. Running the first option only, `Instructor` is the principle entity (`OfficeAssignment` has a PK which is FK to `Instructor`).

Comment: @GertArnold I know that, but what about the second one? What is difference between `WithRequiredPrincipal` and `WithOptional`?

Comment: You know that? You claim there's no difference. There *is* a difference. In the second mapping `OfficeAssignment` is the principle.

Comment: @GertArnold Do you mean they must not generate the same sql?

Comment: With those models the only difference will be the foreign key constraint. The first will add a foreign key to Instructor, the second will put a fk on OfficeAssignment. If OfficeAssignment had a key like "OfficeAssignmentId" and InstructorId as the FK it would open up other possibilities.